Google Maps API - Marker not working with a styled map
I'm trying to create a map with styles and markers.
The styled map works fine--but the marker is not showing.
What am I doing wrong?
I tried many solutions that are submitted here and reddit but none seems to work.
Here is the code:

function initMap() {
  // Styles a map in night mode.


  const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    center: { lat: 40.674, lng: -73.945 },
    zoom: 12,
    disableDefaultUI: true,



    styles: [
    {
        "featureType": "all",
        "elementType": "all",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "visibility": "on"
            },
            {
                "color": "#3b6c39"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "all",
        "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "saturation": 36
            },
            {
                "color": "#000000"
            },
            {
                "lightness": 40
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "all",
        "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "visibility": "on"
            },
            {
                "color": "#000000"
            },
            {
                "lightness": 16
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "all",
        "elementType": "labels.icon",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "visibility": "off"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "administrative",
        "elementType": "geometry.fill",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "color": "#000000"
            },
            {
                "lightness": 20
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "administrative",
        "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "color": "#000000"
            },
            {
                "lightness": 17
            },
            {
                "weight": 1.2
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "landscape",
        "elementType": "geometry",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "color": "#000000"
            },
            {
                "lightness": 20
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "poi",
        "elementType": "geometry",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "color": "#000000"
            },
            {
                "lightness": 21
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "road.highway",
        "elementType": "geometry.fill",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "color": "#000000"
            },
            {
                "lightness": 17
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "road.highway",
        "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "color": "#000000"
            },
            {
                "lightness": 29
            },
            {
                "weight": 0.2
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "road.arterial",
        "elementType": "geometry",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "color": "#000000"
            },
            {
                "lightness": 18
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "road.local",
        "elementType": "geometry",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "color": "#000000"
            },
            {
                "lightness": 16
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "transit",
        "elementType": "geometry",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "color": "#000000"
            },
            {
                "lightness": 19
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "water",
        "elementType": "geometry",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "color": "#1a1a1a"
            },
            {
                "lightness": 17
            }
        ]
    }
]
});
    const { AdvancedMarkerElement } = await google.maps.importLibrary("marker");
  const marker = new AdvancedMarkerElement({
    map,
    position: { lat: 40.73711331385601, lng: -73.99081789299093 },
  });
}

window.initMap = initMap;



I'm not asking to code the entire map for me with styles and markers but just to set me on the right path on how to make it work.

your initMap function is not async therefore you can't await in it. I guess you didn't bother checking the browser console for errors?

by the way, how can The styled map works fine since initMap won't ever run the way you've shown it?

You can't use advanced markers and map styles together.  Either use a "legacy" marker or use a mapId.

When I run the posted code I get an error:
"Uncaught SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules",

(as @Bravo indicated in his comment)
You can't use advanced markers and map styles together.  Either use a "legacy" marker or use a mapId.
working code snippet using map styles and legacy marker:


function initMap() {
  // Styles a map in night mode.


  const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    center: { lat: 40.674, lng: -73.945 },
    zoom: 12,
    // mapId: '4504f8b37365c3d0',
    disableDefaultUI: true,



    styles: [
    {
        "featureType": "all",
        "elementType": "all",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "visibility": "on"
            },
            {
                "color": "#3b6c39"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "all",
        "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "saturation": 36
            },
            {
                "color": "#000000"
            },
            {
                "lightness": 40
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "all",
        "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "visibility": "on"
            },
            {
                "color": "#000000"
            },
            {
                "lightness": 16
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "all",
        "elementType": "labels.icon",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "visibility": "off"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "administrative",
        "elementType": "geometry.fill",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "color": "#000000"
            },
            {
                "lightness": 20
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "administrative",
        "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "color": "#000000"
            },
            {
                "lightness": 17
            },
            {
                "weight": 1.2
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "landscape",
        "elementType": "geometry",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "color": "#000000"
            },
            {
                "lightness": 20
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "poi",
        "elementType": "geometry",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "color": "#000000"
            },
            {
                "lightness": 21
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "road.highway",
        "elementType": "geometry.fill",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "color": "#000000"
            },
            {
                "lightness": 17
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "road.highway",
        "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "color": "#000000"
            },
            {
                "lightness": 29
            },
            {
                "weight": 0.2
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "road.arterial",
        "elementType": "geometry",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "color": "#000000"
            },
            {
                "lightness": 18
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "road.local",
        "elementType": "geometry",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "color": "#000000"
            },
            {
                "lightness": 16
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "transit",
        "elementType": "geometry",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "color": "#000000"
            },
            {
                "lightness": 19
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "water",
        "elementType": "geometry",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "color": "#1a1a1a"
            },
            {
                "lightness": 17
            }
        ]
    }
]
});
  const marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map,
    position: { lat: 40.73711331385601, lng: -73.99081789299093 },
  });
  map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
}

window.initMap = initMap;
#map {
  height: 100%;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Google Maps Javascript API v3</title>

</head>

<body>
  <div id="map"></div>

  <!-- 
      The `defer` attribute causes the script to execute after the full HTML
      document has been parsed. For non-blocking uses, avoiding race conditions,
      and consistent behavior across browsers, consider loading using Promises. See
      https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/load-maps-js-api
      for more information.
      -->
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap&v=weekly&loading=async" defer></script>
</body>

</html>




